# install odoo 12 on ubuntu 18.04 - module not founderror : no module named 'babel'

Tags: 18.04, odoo

I've created a new virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to install Odoo 12 from [this link](https://www.technaureus.com/how-install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-18-4-odoo-installation/), but I'm facing error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it solves your particular issue with Babel:

```
sudo -H pip3 install babel
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't install odoo manually by running those commmands.

I have a better solution for this.(without any error you will enjoy odoo)

odoo installtion script:-

https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/tree/12.0

just download this and open up terminal --> go to your downloads folder where you downloaded this script

run script by `sudo ./odoo_install.sh`

Comment: this answer is the best solution for this case , thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You need intall all required modules Python for Odoo works.
Go to Odoo path (generally /opt/odoo) and exec

```
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

If you need just resolve babel instalation, so

```
    pip3 install babel
```

Answer (score 0):

Step five, sub-step 2 of [the specified process](https://www.technaureus.com/how-install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-18-4-odoo-installation/) mentioned the installation of `Babel` and that's case sensitive.

It specifies (emphasis mine):

> pip3 install **Babel** decorator docutils ebaysdk feedparser gevent greenlet html2text Jinja2 lxml Mako MarkupSafe mock num2words ofxparse passlib Pillow psutil psycogreen psycopg2 pydot pyparsing PyPDF2 pyserial python-dateutil python-openid pytz pyusb PyYAML qrcode reportlab requests six suds-jurko vatnumber vobject Werkzeug XlsxWriter xlwt xlrd

After switching to the odoo user, please retry step five and make sure it's entered as **Babel** not *babel* because the error message you provided says the Python package management system could not find *babel* in lowercase. Typically, that's caused by a typing error.

Comment: I'm copying command and running it exactly like written .